# Open sets in topology and metric spaces

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $\tau$ = { $\emptyset,[0,1],\mathbb{R}$}

($\mathbb{R},\tau$) is a topological space, right? Since the intersection of any of the sets in $\tau$ is itself in $\tau$, and same for the union.  But doesn't this make [0,1] an open set w.r.t. $\tau$, conflicting with [0,1] being closed in $\mathbb{R}$?

Thanks!

Comment: You know that $[0,1]$ is closed *in the * **usual** *topology of* $\mathbb{R}$, which has nothing to do with the topology $\tau$ you described. Moreover, there can be (non-trivial) sets which are open and closed with respect to some topology (spaces with that property are called *disconnected*. For example discrete topologies on non-unitary sets).

Answer (score 1):

Which set is "open" or "closed" depends on the topology of the space and in fact is the topology of the space. In your topology $\tau$ the set $[0,1]$ is open, but in the standard topology on $\mathbb R$, it is in fact closed.

The standard topology on $\mathbb R$ is induced by the metric $d: (x,y) \mapsto |x-y|$. Here induced means that we use this metric to define a collection of open sets (called a basis) which generate a topology. In particular these open balls are defined as $$B_r(x) = \{p \in \mathbb R \mid d(x,p) < r\}.$$ This definition works for any metric over any space. The open balls of $\mathbb R$ under the Euclidean metric are just the open intervals.